# Run svn as android project

Tags: android, svn

i was looking all over the net but was unable to find solution for my problem, I imported project into eclipse Import -> Checkout Projects using Svn. After the project was imported i tried to run it as android app but the project hasn't Android library, can't add library with right click -> build path, please help.

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to achieve. Is the project that you tried to import an Android Library project? You cannot _run_ a library project.

Comment: When you import there is a "check out as a project configured using the new project wizard" option. select that and choose android project

Comment: I am trying to import android app from   http://code.google.com/p/shelves/source/checkout. I tried "check out as a project configured using the new project wizard" option but then Shelve project was just one folder in file structure.

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/shelves/source/browse/ is the correct link. Download all files and placed them at correct location in your android project..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have just checked out is an android project.

But as there is no .project and .classpath files, this project is not set up to run with eclipse by default.

In order to have this project recognised as an Android project by Eclipse, you need to add the "Android Nature" to your project.

The .project file is not visible from Eclipse but you can find it under the root directory of the Shelves project once you imported it into Eclipse.

Edit your .project file and make it look like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<projectDescription>
    <name>Shelves</name>
    <comment></comment>
    <projects>
    </projects>
    <buildSpec>
        <buildCommand>
            <name>com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ResourceManagerBuilder</name>
            <arguments>
            </arguments>
        </buildCommand>
        <buildCommand>
            <name>com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.PreCompilerBuilder</name>
            <arguments>
            </arguments>
        </buildCommand>
        <buildCommand>
            <name>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder</name>
            <arguments>
            </arguments>
        </buildCommand>
        <buildCommand>
            <name>com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ApkBuilder</name>
            <arguments>
            </arguments>
        </buildCommand>
    </buildSpec>
    <natures>
        <nature>com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.AndroidNature</nature>
        <nature>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature</nature>
    </natures>
</projectDescription>
```

Also make sure you checkout

> http://shelves.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Shelves

and not

> http://shelves.googlecode.com/svn/trunk

You also have to create a .classpath file at the root of the Shelves project and make it look exactly as follows :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="gen"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ANDROID_FRAMEWORK"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.LIBRARIES"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin/classes"/>
</classpath>
```

Make sure your SDK is properly installed and your project.properties is targetting an installed SDK version. For example if you have SDK API-Level 10 installed :

```
# Project target.
target=android-10
```

Then close the project, open it again, make project > Clean..., refresh, bla bla bla ... until it works.

Comment: I did as you said, but i get this two errors: Description Resource Path Location Type
The project was not built since its build path is incomplete. Cannot find the class file for java.lang.Object. Fix the build path then try building this project Shelves  Unknown Java Problem
and Description Resource Path Location Type
The type java.lang.Object cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files ShelvesView.java /Shelves/src/org/curiouscreature/android/shelves/view line 1 Java Problem

Comment: Did you updated ADT to the latest version ? http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html At the top right of the project folder do you see the little Android icon ?

Comment: If you do, you should : Right click on project > Run as > Android application.

Comment: The problem is i don't have android icon in project folder.

Comment: That means that the project is not treated as an Android project. It looks like you have a problem with your .project file and the android nature.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that the given answer is the best practice. A lot of times projects in the repos do not have the .project or .classpath files (for good reason but that's a different story) so you can "create a project from existing source".

In eclipse there are two options that are similar yet different. File->Import->Import Android Project... and File->New ->Project->Android->Android project from existing code. In the first, the .project and .classpath files are provided but you may have to tweak the build path. In the latter, only the source is provided so that is the option you want to use. Once you select 'Android project from existing code', just browse to the directory that you just checked out and then build the project.